# fpdf display image in table row using table with multilcell

Tags: php, fpdf

I am having trouble displaying image using fpdf library. I use fpdf Table with MultiCells scripts [http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=3 ].

I can display data by calling this function

```
$data = [
  ['A','B','C','image_path'],
  ['A','B','C','image_path'],
  ['A','B','C','image_path'],
];
$pdf->Row($header);
foreach($data as $v) $pdf->Row($v);
```

It will generate data nicely. I want to replace `image_path` with image .  How can I display image using this script?

My pdf will be look like this.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify PDF_MC_Table class Row() functions by using Inhertence.

```
Class Pdf extends PDF_MC_Table{
  protected $imageKey = '';

  public function setImageKey($key){
    $this->imageKey = $key;
  }

  public function Row($data){
    $nb=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++)
      $nb=max($nb,$this->NbLines($this->widths[$i],$data[$i]));
      $h=5*$nb;
      $this->CheckPageBreak($h);
      for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
        $w=$this->widths[$i];
        $a=isset($this->aligns[$i]) ? $this->aligns[$i] : 'L';
        $x=$this->GetX();
        $y=$this->GetY();
        $this->Rect($x,$y,$w,$h);

        //modify functions for image 
        if(!empty($this->imageKey) && in_array($i,$this->imageKey)){
          $ih = $h - 0.5;
          $iw = $w - 0.5;
          $ix = $x + 0.25;
          $iy = $y + 0.25;
          $this->MultiCell($w,5,$this->Image ($data[$i],$ix,$iy,$iw,$ih),0,$a);
        }
        else
          $this->MultiCell($w,5,$data[$i],0,$a);
        $this->SetXY($x+$w,$y);
      }
      $this->Ln($h);
    }
  }

}
```

Now call this function like this

```
$data = [
  ['A','B','C','image_path'],
  ['A','B','C','image_path'],
  ['A','B','C','image_path'],
];

$pdf = new Pdf();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->setImageKey = [4];
$pdf->Row($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just elaborating on @Alien's code: the line height on the image cell is the same as the line height for text cells, wich at first seems logical, but there's a bug here: if all your texts are one liners and your image is higher than your text height, the image will overlap the cell below (next row), so the height of the cell containing the image has to be recalculated:

First I added a function to resize the image to the proper width/height for displaying (mantaining the original w/h ratio):

```
    function scaleimage($img_path, $maxw = NULL, $maxh = NULL) {
    $img = getimagesize($img_path);
    if ($img) {
        $w = $img[0];
        $h = $img[1];

        $dim = array('w', 'h');
        foreach ($dim AS $val) {
            $max = "max{$val}";
            if (${$val} > ${$max} && ${$max}) {
                $alt = ($val == 'w') ? 'h' : 'w';
                $ratio = ${$alt} / ${$val};
                ${$val} = ${$max};
                ${$alt} = ${$val} * $ratio;
            }
        }
        return array((int) $w, (int) $h);
    }
}
```

Then modified @Alien's code (showed relevant part only):

```
//modify functions for image 
if (!empty($this->imageKey) && in_array($i, $this->imageKey)) {                
    $ih = $h - 0.5;
    $iw = $w - 0.5;
    $ix = $x + 0.25;
    $iy = $y + 1;    // increased top gap, adjust as needed  
            
    // adjusted display width/height
    $imgw = scaleimage($data[$i], $iw, $ih)[0];
    $imgh = scaleimage($data[$i], $iw, $ih)[1];
            
    $this->MultiCell($w, 5, $this->Image($data[$i], $ix, $iy, $imgw, $imgh), 0, $a);
}
```